# Should we allow answers to identification requests to list a bunch of titles?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

So far, most of the answers to identification requests contain a single title, which is good, because users can upvote/downvote based on the correlation between the single series suggested in the answer and the description in the question.

However, there are cases where some users just list a bunch of titles as guesses. This could be due to the following reasons:

- The question is under-specified. **The question should be put on hold (closed) until the OP makes an adequate edit.**
- The answer just makes random guesses without explaining how it matches the description in the question. **The answer should be deleted.**
- The answer focuses on a single special characteristic in the description and lists a few titles that match the characteristic. **Quite borderline**

And the matter becomes more complicated if the OP checks back before the community can act on the answers.

This question prompted me to bring up this issue:

[Korean manhwa about a guy who cannot fight, but ends up winning every fight he is in](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20342/korean-manhwa-about-a-guy-who-cannot-fight-but-ends-up-winning-every-fight-he-i)

<sup>Basically, after the OP edited to add clues, the answerer answered the question focusing on a trait of the protagonist, and provided a list of other titles whose protagonists have the same trait. Since the OP was around, he went through the list and found what he was looking for. Then he was told to accept the answer which lists out everything instead of writing his own answer.</sup>

As a result, the question got stuck with a misleading answer.

Using the question above as a case study, I think we need some sort of requirement for this sort of pot shots answers. While editing is an option, it is not scalable when the site has more producers than maintainers, and not everyone knows what to do in this case - to practically destroy most of the content in the answer, or to leave it alone in a confusing manner.

Answer (score 5):

There's a good reason users can post multiple answers on the same question.

If you have multiple guesses, and they're fundamentally different answers, post multiple answers.